# Mongos with --upgrade: I have stopped the balancer but

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-16.04

I have a trouble after switching from Ubuntu 14.x to 16.x. MongoDB processes like configuration servers, arbiter and the main MongoDB server are running well. I can access to my databases with the Mongo shell.

But the problem comes with mongos. It crashes when I want to launch it (with `--upgrade`) saying that the balancer must be stopped before running an upgrade. But I have stopped it a few seconds earlier!

With the Mongo shell I did:

```
sh.stopBalancer ()
```

Then I verified the state with:

```
sh.getBalancerState ()
```

The returned value is `false`.

But I still get the same error from mongos! (balancer must be stopped for config upgrade)

Few lines before (in the mongos output) I got this:

> scoped connection to xxx not being returned to the pool

But I don't understand the sentence. I don't know if it's related to my problem.

So the final question: how could I start mongos successfully?